# Como procurar palavras com javascript?

Tags: javascript

Oi. Preciso pegar a responseTxt que recebi de uma página e procurar elementos nele. Os elementos que preciso exibir são os procedentes de uma tag chamada "nome name".

Exemplo:

No arquivo tem algumas linhas do tipo:

```
string(numero) = "nodo=""nome"
```

Preciso achar cada lugar em que está escrito `"nodo="` e pegar cada palavra seguida por ele. No caso, se aparecer 3 ocorrências de `"nodo="` e cada uma tiver uma palavra (ex: uma tem pedra, outra papel e outra tesoura), tenho que pegar essas 3 ocorrências de `nodo=` e pegar as palavras de cada uma e imprimi-las na tela.

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo mais claro? essas aspas estão meio esquesitas para ter numa string `"nodo=""nome"`? junta a string que tens pf.

Comment: É uma resposta de um post. Eu faço post via ajax num site e recebo a responseTxt. Mas essa responseTxt esta como o site envia. Eu queria filtrar. Ele manda tudo assim, como no exemplo. Mas tem umaspartes que esta escrito string e algo fora do contexto e outras (as que me interesso) esta escrito "nodo name=""document" ( ou outras palavras). Espero que tenha ficado mais claro. So quero procurar por palavras na responseTxt precedidas por um "nodo name=", pois sao essas que desejo imprimir na tela. Abraço!

Comment: Nao tenho aqui agora a string completa do responseTxt mas é bem assim (o modelo) ... String(46)=> "name=""nome""/string" string (58)=> "nodo name=""documento""/html" string (35)=>"idade""40""qualquercoisa" string (43)=> "nodo name=""hoje""algoaqui" . Obs: Isso é um modela de como é, nap lembro o que vem escrito nos outros "string". Eu preciso pegar a palavra seguinte ao "nodo name="

Comment: Luciano, para cada string "string(n) => ..." possui uma quebra de linha?

Comment: Toby sim! La por 11 hrs~ 12 hrs chego em casa ai posto a resposta dada pelo servidor no responseTxt. Mas cada string (n) ele imprime como uma linha

Comment: Segue abaixo a resposta do servidor (responseTxt), que preciso pegar apenas as palavras após node name:      Resposta do servidor: array(173) {
[0]=>
string(10) "<document>"
[1]=>
string(24) "<nodo name="background">"
[2]=>
string(10) "<id>1</id>"
[3]=>
string(34) "<ocorrencia>0.3115942</ocorrencia>"
[4]=>
string(23) "<relacoes name="image">"
[5]=>
string(23) "<conexoes>48</conexoes>"
[6]=>
string(11) "</relacoes>"
[7]=>

Comment: @LucianoZancan, poderia atualizar a sua pergunta com conteúdo do ResponseText? este tipo de informação não fica visível dentro de uma comentario.

Comment: @LucianoZancan, atualizei a resposta, dá uma olhada nela para ver se resolve o seu problema.

Comment: Utilize uma expressão regular para procurar os padrões.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oi, você pode encontrar uma palavra usando o método indexOf('suaPalavra');

O método irá retornar o index da palavra buscada, no caso, acredito que ficará algo assim:

```
var busca = "nodo=";
var indexBusca = seuRetorno.indexOf(busca);
```

Para testar se encontrou basta verificar o valor retornado, no caso, se for diferente de -1 é que a palavra foi localizada.

```
if (indexBusca != -1) {
    // seu código
}
```

Abraços.

Comment: A sua resposta tem dois problemas. o primeiro é que ela retorna apenas a primeira incidência do texto "node=", o segundo é que o Autor da Pergunta não está interessado neste texto, mas sim no valor atribuído a ele.

Answer (score 0):

@LucianoZancan, baseado no seu ultimo exemplo, acredito que o ResponseText se trata de um documento XML serializado de uma maneira não convencional.

Neste caso o interresante é converter o ResponseText para um documento XML e então trabalhar com o documento XML:

Uma vez que tenhamos o documento XML, então podemos procurar todas as `tags nomes` e recuperar a `propriedade name` das mesmas.

```js
var responseText = '\
array(9) {\n\
    [0]=> string(10) "<document>"\n\
    [1]=> string(24) "<nodo name="background">"\n\
    [2]=> string(10) "<id>1</id>"\n\
    [3]=> string(34) "<ocorrencia>0.3115942</ocorrencia>"\n\
    [4]=> string(23) "<relacoes name="image">"\n\
    [5]=> string(23) "<conexoes>48</conexoes>"\n\
    [6]=> string(11) "</relacoes>"\n\
    [7]=> string(11) "</nodo>"\n\
    [8]=> string(11) "</document>"\n\
}\
';

var conteudoText = responseText.split("\n");
var conteudoXML =  [];
for (var indice in conteudoText) {    
    var text = conteudoText[indice];
    var indice = text.indexOf('"');
    if (indice >= 0) {
        var xml = text.substring(indice + 1, text.length - 1);
        conteudoXML.push(xml);
    }
}

var documentXML = new DOMParser().parseFromString(conteudoXML.join("\n"),"text/xml");

var nodos = documentXML.getElementsByTagName("nodo");
for (var indice = 0; indice < nodos.length; indice++) {
    var nodo = nodos[indice];
    console.log(nodo.getAttribute("name"));
}
```

**EDIT: As soluções abaixo foram tentativas de resposta realizadas quando o autor da pergunta não havia dado dados suficientes, irei maten-las por considera-las interessantes.**

Caso você queira trabalhar com texto puro, pode procurar a ocorrência do texto "node name=" e então recupera o valor seguinte que está entre aspas.

```js
var responseText  = '\
String (46)=> "name=""nome""/string" \
String (58)=> "nodo name=""documento""/html" \
String (35)=> "idade""40""qualquercoisa" \
String (43)=> "nodo name=""hoje""algoaqui" \
';

function encontrarValores(string, chave, separador, delimitador){
    var indice = string.indexOf(chave, 0);
    var valores = [];

    do {        
        
        var iniIndice = indice + chave.length + separador.length + delimitador.length;
        var fimIndice = string.indexOf(delimitador, iniIndice);
        var valor = string.substring(iniIndice, fimIndice);        
        valores.push(valor);
        indice = string.indexOf(chave, indice + 1);
      
    } while (indice >= 0);
    return valores;
}

var valores = encontrarValores(responseText, 'nodo name', '=', '""')
console.log(valores);
```

Porem caso estivesse a trabalhar com HTML, poderia simplesmente fazer o seguinte:

```js
var responseText  = '\
    <div nodo="externa">\
        <div nodo="interna 1">Interna 1</div>\
        <div nodo="interna 2">Interna 2</div>\
        <div nodo="interna 3">Interna 3</div>\
    </div">\
';

var container = document.createElement("div");
container.innerHTML = responseText;


var elements = container.querySelectorAll("[nodo]");
for (var indice in elements) {
    var element = elements[indice];
    if (element.nodeType == 1) {
        console.log(element.getAttribute("nodo"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Agora que vi o comentário do Autor, daqui a pouco adiciono coloco algo util para ele.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar uma **regexp** para fazer isso:

Exemplo:

Coloquei no meio do texto duas expressões no formato que você indicou para exemplificar:

- `[1]=> string(24) "<nodo name="background">" [1243]=> string(24) "<nodo name="xpto">"`
- o resultado será: `["background","xpto"]`

```js
var text = 'array(173) { [0]=> string(10) "<document>" [1]=> string(24) "<nodo name="background">" [1243]=> string(24) "<nodo name="xpto">" [2]=> string(10) "<id>1</id>" [3]=> string(34) "<ocorrencia>0.3115942</ocorrencia>" [4]=> string(23) "<relacoes name="image">" [5]=> string(23) "<conexoes>48</conexoes>" [6]=> string(11) "</relacoes>" [7]=>';

var items = text.split(/nodo name="([^"]*)"/g);
var count = items.length;
var result = [];
for (var i = 1; i < count; i += 2)
    result.push(items[i]);

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result)
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Não é a forma mais performática do mundo, mas é a forma mais fácil de fazer ao meu ver.